# Galaxy Readiness Past 100%?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So I've played the multiplayer and incresed my Galactic Readiness to 100%. But then after i played another map i got a 5% "Maximum Galactic Readiness." Does this mean that when the Readiness decreases, it will only decrease to 55% instead of 50%? i've looked all over for this but i've found no answers.

Comment: I doubt it would affect anything, 100% ought to mean 100%.

Answer (score 6):

When you already have 100% Galactic Readiness, you gain a 5% bonus to XP since it cannot be increased further. I believe that's what the message that popped up was saying.

Edit: Just to clarify my answer since this question has gotten a lot of views: Galactic Readiness cannot go above 100% or below 50%. There's no way to increase the minimum readiness threshold. The 5% mentioned is an XP bonus awarded for completing multiplayer sessions while readiness is maxed out at 100%.

Comment: That is correct.